# Sharepoint/Office365:: Error downloading file

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onedrive

I've been using the following API for download files for my OneDrive users.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841(v=office.15).aspx#bk_FileMethods

The typical URL is of this sort

```
https://{site url}/_api/files('<filename>')/download
```

Now the problem is that if the file contains unicode, specially the character "'" (single quote) then it gives me a 400 response saying the resource is invalid, since the quotes that are enclosing the file name get mixed up with the single quote in filename itself.

Now, I have tried URL encoding of this file name and what not. But the same error everytime.

Microsoft have new API([LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog#Files)) for files which have a way to download the file using file ID. But to get that file ID, one needs to access that API, since this API that I am using doesn't provide a FileID.

Isn't there any way I could overcome this problem using the older API and download such files?

*For example:*
File names like >>> Testing¶)éùûÞ'ï1 - Copy (4).txt

*Error*

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "value": "The expression \"files('Testing¶)éùûÞ'ï1 - Copy (4).txt')/download\" is not valid."
    }
}
```

}

Comment: try encoding the url: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Did that too, same error!